# Apache httpd module to authenticate against web service?

Tags: authentication, module, apache

I'm looking to see if there's an available apache httpd module to do this or if I'll have to write my own.  I want to be able to authenticate and authorize a user based on a RESTful web service call that returns JSON from to our SSO application.  It has to do this:

Extract a cookie value from the request.  If no cookie jump to the redirect.

Construct a URL based on it

Fetch the URL

Check the JSON object for an authorized boolean.  If not authorized redirect to a login application passing the original request URL as a parameter.

If authorized, check the allowed groups against an array in the JSON object.  Return a 401 if not in the list or let the request continue if it is.

We do this with servlet filters in our Java applications, but it would be handy to be able to restrict any URL with it whether it's static content or code.